# How to update transform matrix (NewtonGameDyanmics/OpenGL)?

Tags: c++, opengl, game-physics, physics-engine

I'm trying to simulate rotating box using Newton Physics and OpenGL. This is what i have implemented.

```
float mat44[16] = {
    1,0,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,
    0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,1
};

box.mat = &mat44[0];
box.x_size = 0.50;
box.y_size = 0.50;
box.z_size = 0.50;

nWorld = NewtonCreate(NULL, NULL);

NewtonCollision * collision = NULL;
collision = NewtonCreateBox(nWorld, box.x_size, box.y_size, box.z_size,NULL);
body = NewtonCreateBody(nWorld, collision);
NewtonReleaseCollision (nWorld, collision);
NewtonBodySetMassMatrix(body, 10.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
NewtonBodySetMatrix (body, box.mat);
float omega[3] = {0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f};
NewtonBodySetOmega (body, &omega[0]);
```

inside the rendering loop i'm doing these things.

```
NewtonUpdate(nWorld, time);
float m[16];
NewtonBodyGetMatrix(body, &m[0]);
box.mat = m;
```

my problem is how to draw a cube (actually 8 points) using the matrix(box.mat) ? how can i calculate updated vertex points using the matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You consider the vertex as a column vector and multiply your matrix by it.

```
r.x = v.x * m[0] + v.y * m[1] + v.z * m[2]  + m[3]
r.y = v.x * m[4] + v.y * m[5] + v.z * m[6]  + m[7]
r.z = v.x * m[8] + v.y * m[9] + v.z * m[10] + m[11]
```

Where [ v.x, v.y, v.z, 1 ] is the vertex position and `r` is the output vertex.

Incidentally, if you're using OpenGL, the "correct" thing to do is feed OpenGL the unchanged vertices and simply use `box.mat` as the "model matrix" for OpenGL (part of the model-view matrix).

Comment: please let me know how to do this second part (feed OpenGL the unchanged vertices and simply use box.mat as the "model matrix" for OpenGL)?

Comment: Assuming that the current matrix stack is `GL_MODELVIEW` and that the current matrix on that stack is your view matrix, then you call `glMultTransposeMatrixf(box.mat)`. This assumes you're using row-major matrices, which is the same assumption I used to write the code in my actual answer.

Comment: No, you don't need to transpose Newton matrix to pass it to OpenGL. Simply call glMultMatrixf(m); if m is matrix you get from NewtonBodyGetMatrix function.